# The site's security certificate is not trusted with openssl

Tags: jboss, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to support HTTPS in my web application. Since the certificates from Verisign are costly, I decided to use openssl for generating certificate. Here is the link I referred https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7ConfiguringSSLOnJBossWeb

When I tried to access the application in browser I got the error "The site's security certificate is not trusted". Here is the screenshot,

[image]

Please let me know how I can solve this error? Is it possible to use openssl in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your self signed certificate is not 'trusted' by the browser. It does not recognise it as signed by one of the certificate authorities it trust.

You have two options - tell the browser it can trust the certificate or tell the browser that it can trust the entity which issued it (meaning that if you use the same certificate to sign other certificates; that those also get trusted).

See http://googlechrometutorial.com/google-chrome-advanced-settings/Google-chrome-ssl-settings.html for more information. Once you are in 'Manage certificates' you can import your own ones.

Every browser, every users, will have to go through those steps. So that is practical logistical limit on how much 'production' you can run with this.

Do check out the various 'free' certificates; they are very low cost.

Answer (score 0):

> [MAC SOLUTION](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/1b7V3cs7BS4/GP4mFOufAS4J): The best way that I've found for manually trusting specific site certificates is to use Safari.  See, when you manually trust a certificate in Safari, it requires you to enter your OS X account password.  Safari does this because it stores the certificate details in Keychain Access, a system application that manages all vital data you store on your computer.
>
> This is significant because Chrome also communicates with Keychain Access.  Once the program has a record of the certificate being trusted by Safari, Chrome will also trust the certificate.  You may have to restart the Chrome browser after activating the certificate in Safari to get this to work correctly.
>
> Happy browsing!

Comment: This is an unsafe solution.